# TicTacToe GUI needs optimizing

Tags: java, swing, tic-tac-toe

I've been working on a TicTacToe GUI. While the game works with a proper restart, exit and win conditions; I feel that it could still be better optimized.

I'm not particularly concerned with the cosmetics of the GUI. I'm aware of how to make an interface "pretty", so to speak. I would just like to know if there was a better way I could maybe check win conditions or set things up in general.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BasicGUI {
    private static String piece="O";
    protected static Boolean player=true;
    private static final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
    private static final JPanel panel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,3));
    protected static final JButton[] cells= new JButton[9];
    private static final JButton exitButton=new JButton("Exit");
    private static final JButton restartButton=new JButton("Restart");
    protected static final JLabel winLabel = new JLabel("Make a move");

    public static void main(String[] args){
         createWindow();
         createButtons();
    }


    //Set up frame
    private static void createWindow(){
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(450, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //Add action listeners to buttons
    private static void createButtons(){
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
            cells[i]=new JButton();
            cells[i].addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
            panel.add(cells[i]);
        }
        exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitHandler());
        restartButton.addActionListener(new RestartHandler());
        panel.add(exitButton);
        panel.add(restartButton);
        panel.add(winLabel);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //frame.pack();
    }

    protected static String getPiece(){
        return piece;
    }
    protected static void setPiece(String s){
        piece=s;
    }

    protected static Boolean checkWinner(){
        if(checkCells(cells[0], cells[4], cells[8])) return true;
        else if(checkCells(cells[2], cells[4], cells[6])) return true;

        else if(checkCells(cells[2], cells[5], cells[8])) return true;
        else if(checkCells(cells[1], cells[4], cells[7])) return true;
        else if(checkCells(cells[0], cells[3], cells[6])) return true;

        else if(checkCells(cells[0], cells[1], cells[2])) return true;
        else if(checkCells(cells[3], cells[4], cells[5])) return true;
        else if(checkCells(cells[6], cells[7], cells[8])) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    /*Checks the series in the array to see if they contain the same piece,
    * resulting in a win condition. */
    private static Boolean checkCells(JButton cell1, JButton cell2, JButton cell3){
        return(cell1.getText()==getPiece() &&
               cell2.getText()==getPiece() &&
               cell3.getText()==getPiece()
        );
    }
}

class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //Sets the button clicked to the piece then disables the button
        JButton pressedButton=(JButton)(e.getSource());
        pressedButton.setText(BasicGUI.getPiece());
        pressedButton.setEnabled(false);

        //If there is no winner; change the piece and player then exit method
        if(!BasicGUI.checkWinner()){
            BasicGUI.player=!BasicGUI.player;
            String changePiece=(BasicGUI.player)? "O":"X";
            BasicGUI.setPiece(changePiece);
            BasicGUI.winLabel.setText(BasicGUI.getPiece()+" make a move");
            return;
        }
        //If a win condition is found, disable all the buttons for the game an show who won
        for(JButton c:BasicGUI.cells){
            c.setEnabled(false);
            BasicGUI.winLabel.setText("Game over! "+BasicGUI.getPiece()+" won!");
        }
        return;
    }
}

//Exit game if clicked
class ExitHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

//Clear the text on the games buttons and re-enable them if disabled
class RestartHandler implements ActionListener{
    BasicGUI GUI = new BasicGUI();
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        for(JButton c:GUI.cells){
            c.setEnabled(true);
            c.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Improve the `checkWinner` method by introducing the concepts of rows, columns and diagonals.** In this method the cells that belong to the same rows, columns and diagonals are checked. It is simple to calculate the indexes for cells that belong to a row or column by giving the row or column index: Cells in row *r* have indices *r* x *row_length* + *i*, where *i* runs from 0 to *row_length*-1. With this logic, it is easy to write a `checkRow(r)` method and use this in `checkWinner()`. This is less error prone, because there are less magic numbers in the code:

> ```
> protected static Boolean checkWinner() {
>   return 
>     checkDiagonal(0) ||
>     checkDiagonal(1) ||
>     checkRow(0) ||
>     checkRow(1) ||
>     checkRow(2) ||
>     checkColumn(0) ||
>     checkColumn(1) ||
>     checkColumn(2);
>  }
> ```

The Columns can be calculated equally simply. The Diagonals might need some thought.

2. **Multiple exits in the `ButtonHandler. perform` method.**
   You use an if statement to check for a winner, but instead of using an else block, you return the whole method. Having multiple returns in a method makes it harder to read and to adjust later on, in case a common behavior is required after the if block.
3. **Incorrect documentation of `checkCells` method**
   The documentation says it checks for the same value, where the implementation checks that they all have the value of the current player.
4. **Use of `System.exit`**
   In general it is better to avoid this abrupt way of program termination to increase reusability. In this case, closing the window will halt the application.
5. **Reuse of `ButtonHandler` instance**
   Each button has a separate instance of this handler, but since the handler has no state, this is not necessary. (Might be matter of taste)

Comment: Some solid advice. May I ask why using System.exit is frowned upon in general?

Answer (score 6):

A few points:

First of all, your formatting is inconsistent. You have stuff like:

```
protected static Boolean player=true;
```

And:

```
private static final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
```

Choose one and stick with it. I suggest the second option, as it is easier to read.

Your `checkWinner()` method looks nice, but `if` statements without braces makes me nervous. Try:

```
protected static Boolean checkWinner() {
    if (checkCells(cells[0], cells[4], cells[8])) { // Diagonal
        return true;
    } else if (checkCells(cells[2], cells[4], cells[6])) {
        return true;
    } else if (checkCells(cells[2], cells[5], cells[8])) { // Horizontal
        return true;
    } else if (checkCells(cells[1], cells[4], cells[7])) {
        return true;
    } else if (checkCells(cells[0], cells[3], cells[6])) {
        return true;
    } else if (checkCells(cells[0], cells[1], cells[2])) { // Vertical
        return true;
    } else if (checkCells(cells[3], cells[4], cells[5])) {
        return true;
    } else if (checkCells(cells[6], cells[7], cells[8])) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But that now wastes space. I would group everything together:

```
protected static Boolean checkWinner() {
    return checkCells(cells[0], cells[4], cells[8]) // Diagonal
            || checkCells(cells[2], cells[4], cells[6])
            || checkCells(cells[2], cells[5], cells[8]) // Vertical
            || checkCells(cells[1], cells[4], cells[7])
            || checkCells(cells[0], cells[3], cells[6])
            || checkCells(cells[0], cells[1], cells[2]) // Horizontal
            || checkCells(cells[3], cells[4], cells[5])
            || checkCells(cells[6], cells[7], cells[8]);
}
```

That looks better, and it makes me less nervous.

---

Probably a big problem is that your code does not handle ties. I will leave that to you, as it is pretty easy.

Comment: Didn't notice my inconsistency, thanks! I did have the braces in place beforehand but removed them to, like you say, avoid wasting space. The or operators are probably best used. I noticed the lack of a tie scenario pretty much as soon as I posted this -.-